# PhoneGap Media Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am trying to get an MP3 to play with phonegap on windows phone 7. I have the following in a javascript block in me head.

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
    var my_media = new Media("test.mp3");
    my_media.play();
    document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML="WORKING";
    }
```

The "testdiv" does show "WORKING", but the .mp3 does not play. The mp3 is set to "Content" on the build action and is in the www folder.

I tried the following as well.

```
   var my_media = new Media("www/test.mp3");
    my_media.play();
```

and also

```
    var my_media = new Media("www\test.mp3");
    my_media.play();
```

EDIT

I have gotten this working. I had to add the following to my WMAppManifest.xml

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
```

And then the path for the mp3 needed the following:

`app/www/test.mp3` or you could try `/app/www/test.mp3`

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going bold trying to figure why I was failing at a seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
my_media = new Media("test.mp3", onSuccess, onError);

   function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

this will give you the error message.

For local mp3 also try this:

1. put your mp3 in lib folder.
2. put you mp3 on remote server.see if its working.

Hope this help
~K

Comment: I am getting an Audio Error 5. I think that must mean "file not found"?

Comment: Could you post how you got it to work for a locally stored Mp3? I am unable to get it working myself and have similar code.

Answer (score 3):

I have gotten this working. I had to add the following to my WMAppManifest.xml

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
```

And then the path for the mp3 needed the following:

`app/www/test.mp3` or you could try `/app/www/test.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

for windows phone 8 I got the local files working by creating an audio folder to store my mp3s and setting the path to www/audio/test.mp3